# Play 2.0.2 with Akka remote system

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, future

I am working with Akka 2 and Play 2.0.2. 
I want to connect the Play Framewrok to a remote Akka system.
I have done the remote configuration and 
the remote referencing of actors but any time 
I try to connect the play framewrok to the Akka remote system. 
I get errors I present the codes snippets below.

code from the play Application.

```
public static Result index() throws InterruptedException { 

      ActorSystem csystem = Akka.system();
      ActorRef localNode = csystem.actorOf(new Props(LocalNode.class),"localNode");
        localNode.tell("Hello");


        Thread.sleep(5000);
        csystem.shutdown();
        return ok(index.render("I am OK"));
  }  
}
```

this is the code from the Play Actor

```
public class LocalNode extends UntypedActor {

    LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);
    Timeout timeout = new Timeout(Duration.create(5 , "seconds"));

    static ActorRef masterActor;

    public void preStart()
    {

        /* Get reference to Master Node*/
         masterActor = getContext().
            actorFor("akka://MasterNode@127.0.0.1:9002/user/masterNode/masterActor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" Future called  ");

        Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(masterActor , message, timeout);

            String result = (String) Await.result(future, timeout.duration());

           log.info("Message from Server", result.toString());  
    }
}
```

code from the Play application conf file

```
#confige the remote connection

localNode {
    akka {
        actor {
            provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
        }
        remote {
            transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
            netty {
                hostname = "127.0.0.1"
                port = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

below is the code from the remote Akka Master node

package Rubine_Cluster;

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
public class MasterNode implements Bootable
{
     final ActorSystem system;

      public MasterNode() {
        system = ActorSystem.create("MasterNode", ConfigFactory.load()
            .getConfig("masterNode"));
        ActorRef masterActor = system.actorOf(new Props(MasterActor.class),"masterActor");
        System.out.println(" Master Node is called ");
      }  
      public void startup() {

      }      
          public void shutdown() {
            system.shutdown();
          }
}
```

below is the code for the remote Akka child Actor

```
public class MasterActor extends UntypedActor {

    public MasterActor(){System.out.println(" the masteractor has been started ");}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        System.out.print(" this is from me to you  "+message.toString());

         if (message instanceof String) {
                // Get reference to the message sender and reply back
                getSender().tell(message + " got something");
                System.out.print(" this is from me to you  "+message.toString());
    }
  }  
}
```

below is the code for the remote Akka system conf file

```
masterNode {

akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 9002
    }
 }
}
}
```

below we have the error ocode:

```
[ERROR] [10/01/2012 03:03:21.646] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2]
[akka://application/user/localNode] sending to terminated ref breaks promises
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: sending to terminated ref breaks promises
        at akka.pattern.AskSupport$class.ask(AskSupport.scala:76)
        at akka.pattern.package$.ask(package.scala:43)
        at akka.pattern.Patterns$.ask(Patterns.scala:41)
        at akka.pattern.Patterns.ask(Patterns.scala)
        at controllers.LocalNode.onReceive(LocalNode.java:32)
        at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(UntypedActor.scala:1
54)
        at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(UntypedActor.scala:1
53)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318)
        at akka.actor.UntypedActor.apply(UntypedActor.scala:93)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:179)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(
AbstractDispatcher.scala:516)
        at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
        at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
        at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479)
        at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

I am doing a project for submission can someone help with this problem any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't shut down csystem since it is Play's ActorSystem.
2. You have: "actorFor("akka://MasterNode@127.0.0.1:9002/user/masterNode/masterActor");" but you do not have such a parent ("masterNode") for "masterActor"

Comment: so is the system container not the parent of the masterActor actor object

Comment: No, please read the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/general/addressing.html